# Sed bug causes last line to be lost from file output stream?

Tags: xml, bash, sed

All,

I have a really simple Sed command as follows

```
sed s/XXXX/TestValue/  >> new.xml <template.xml
```

I am using Sed to edit a template XML file before I send it.

**Input File >> template.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EventMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
        <host>testserver.intern.nat.com</host>
        <sourceSystem>EDW</sourceSystem>
        <EventEntity>
            <EventEntityID>XXXX</EventEntityID>
            <EventEntityType>Confirm Batch Receipt</EventEntityType>
        </EventEntity>
    </EventMessage>
```

Then after Sed has processed the file and replace the "XXXX" value, the output file called new.xml loses the last closing element tag

**Output File >> new.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
    <host>testserver.intern.nat.com</host>
    <sourceSystem>EDW</sourceSystem>
    <EventEntity>
        <EventEntityID>Batch_123.csv</EventEntityID>
        <EventEntityType>Confirm Batch Receipt</EventEntityType>
    </EventEntity>
---closing tag missing ---
```

Its as though Sed closes the output stream before the last line in the XML file.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a newline character at the end of the `</EventMessage>` line in template.xml?

Comment: Nope, but there is a new line in the output xml (blank line). I have made sure its EOL conversion is in UNIX when editing remotely

Comment: Is there a newline after the last line in the input file?

Comment: No, I checked on Notepad++ and Vi

Comment: Just did an octal on the file and last sequence is 0001343

Comment: Work fine with a AIX/KSH sed. Try with -posix option maybe. Sed, even working line by line, should take aware of last line. Try to debug a =;l; before your command top show the working line (buffer in fact) and line number of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the missing newline on the fly because `sed` only processes complete lines (i. e. with newlines at their end):

```
(cat input.txt; echo) | sed … > output.txt
```

Comment: Ok thanks for that, but it seems a bit strange that sed requires a newline character at each line before processing the next one.

Comment: Yeah, it's a line based stream editor from ancient times when line editing was common.  Can't help it but that trap is full of programmers by the years ;-)